# quill doesn't see the event inside 'text-change'

Tags: javascript, quill

```
this.editor.on('text-change', function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
...someCode 
if(some condition) {
const range  = this.editor.getSelection()}}
```

but i can see this error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelection')**

this.editor equals **quill** and i can use this instead of quill, it's worked in other function

Answer (score 0):

it was because of the scope, if you declare a variable in advance and put the editor there, everything is fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).